# Why was it necessary to destroy the experiment

Tags: westworld-2016

In Westworld s2e4 we see an experiment that has been run many times and every time afterwards it is totally incinerated. Why was it necessary to do this rather than just run it again with a new subject?

Comment: Great question, but I have a feeling there won't be a reasonable explanation - It has the sense of something chosen for visual impact and/or symbolism. And season 2 hasn't been much for explaining things across the board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The out of universe answer: It was simple poetic license and the director using the [Rule of Cool](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleOfCool). Lisa Joy directed this episode, and used fire imagery throughout to evoke ideas of the devil, and of cleansing away the past. From Entertainment Weekly:

> EW: ... **At first, I was wondering why they would burn the room rather than just switch him off and dump the body.** Then in the end, it seemed clear you were going for a metaphor of him being in hell. But [I] was wondering if you came up with a technical explanation for why they had to refurbish that room with the same stuff 150 times?
>
> LJ: **Part of it is it’s just visually cool**. You’re starting with him lighting a cigarette and the Rolling Stones song “Play With Fire.” He talks about devils and angels. **I wanted to ask: Can you have sympathy for the devil?** You see two elemental forces in this episode. You also see rain in Westworld for the first time with the battle with the Man in Black, a baptism in that fight scene. **And then you see fire. Both can represent the cleansing away of the past, and the question is whether the past can really ever be washed away, or does it always repeat one way or another.**
>
> <sup>- [Westworld showrunner reveals what you missed in 'Riddle of the Sphinx'](https://ew.com/tv/2018/05/13/westworld-lisa-joy-riddle-of-the-sphinx/)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

They were testing for 'fidelity'. The experimentally created person's responses were recorded and verified in detail. A goal being to match another person perfectly - or at least better than last time.

So the experimental setup had to be identical each time. They could not re-use furniture or the experimental body; either would be somewhat more worn in each successive experiment. They did a lot of experiments, and small differences might result in slightly different reactions.  They did not want to wonder: is this synthetic person reacting strange due to still present faults, or merely irritated after listening to a worn-down vinyl record while exercising? Butterfly effects adds up quickly.